# Oracle SQL query issue

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using oracle's SQL Developer. To begin with, I have this table:

```
Name           Null     Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)  
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)
```

I would like to retrieve(select)  the ID of the department in which are the most employees.
I managed through a statement to retrieve all the numbers of the employees in every department:

```
select count(employee_id), department_id
from employees
group by department_id;
```

It gives me something like:

```
count(employee_id)   |     department_id
---------------------|------------------
      6                       100
     16                        30
      1                        12
```

What I would like to do is ONLY to retrieve the `department_id` 30, which (in this case) has the most employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to do this in Oracle:

```
select department_id
from (select count(employee_id), department_id
      from employees
      group by department_id
      order by count(employee_id) desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

If you have potential duplicates and want all the department ids, then a join to the max or analytic function is a better approach.  For example:

```
select department_id
from (select count(employee_id), department_id,
             rank() over (order by count(employee_id) desc) as seqnum
      from employees
      group by department_id
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. The first snippet works perfectly but the second one gives me more than one result.

Comment: @Theo. . . . The `desc` will fix that problem (I actually fixed it before I read your comment).